# Unknown tablet without Android

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

A friend of mine offered me a tablet that he doesn't know the brand, he tried to install some version of Cyanogenmod with ClockworkMod.

Now the tablet just bootloops and I can only access Clockwork with recovery mode.

Factory reset or what-so-ever doesn't help now. I only have 2 options:

- Find out the brand with only Clockwork and get a custom ROM for it
- Install a general Android version (if that exists)

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Youn won't probaly find help step by step here if that is what you mean. I also find it very problematic you got an unidentified device and simply install a random Cyanogenmod build without thinking twice.

Comment: @xangua OP didn't flash CM, his friend did. Read it again. BTW, step by step help is what alot of answers on Stack Exchange provide. Try to **`encourage`**, not **`discourage`**.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is bootlooping is probably because cyanogenmod was installed and it isn't for that device.

There should be serial/model number on the back of the device. This is a requirement (AFAIK) by the [FCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_Declaration_of_Conformity).

> The certification mark is a stand-alone logo (as shown above) for the part 18 class of devices while, for the part 15 class, along with the logo, the label should display other data viz, the trade name of the product, the model number, and information whether the device was tested after assembling, or assembled from tested components.

You should be able to use that to figure out what device it is. Then you can see if you can find a version of android for it from that.